# Bootstrap push/pull questions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I am kind of new to the responsive design and i have some issues working with push pull in bootstrap.

First question is it correct to write rows like that?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <h1>Projects:</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <textarea class="form-control preventEdit" rows="5" style="min-width: 100%" disabled>PRO</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <h1>Description:</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <textarea class="form-control preventEdit" rows="5" style="min-width: 100%" disabled>DES</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
```

so at this moment I have something that looks like this at extra small and small devices:

|TEXT1|

|BOX1|

|TEXT2|

|BOX2|

But I need to make the layout look like this at medium and bigger

|TEXT1||TEXT2|

|BOX1 ||BOX2 |

Tried doing it with push and pull but the result is nothing like I wanted. The boxes just flies away.

the code I tried:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <h1>Projects:</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6 ">
            <textarea class="form-control preventEdit" rows="5" style="min-width: 100%" disabled>PRO</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
            <h1>Description:</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <textarea class="form-control preventEdit" rows="5" style="min-width: 100%" disabled>DES</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas how to get the result I need?

Thank you for you help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat each text/box combo as a single entity and forget about worrying about push/pulls:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      <div>
        <h1>Projects:</h1>
        <textarea class="form-control preventEdit" rows="5" style="min-width: 100%" disabled>PRO</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      <div>
        <h1>Description:</h1>
        <textarea class="form-control preventEdit" rows="5" style="min-width: 100%" disabled>DES</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple solution :) don't know why I was trying something complicated :D